# HighCharts Solid Gauge Chart not displaying ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Using Highcharts 5.0.11 .JS version and Solid Gauge.
Page has two temperature Gauges which are going to be half crescent in shape.
The first Gauge Internal Temperature is fine, but when trying to play with settings to create an inverse Gauge the chart stops displaying ticks and labels associated to them as shown below along with link to my fiddle. The key thing I have found is that when ever the start angle is higher than the end angle this is the result and the problem occurs.

[image: Results]
[JS Fiddle Here to show Code for above](http://jsfiddle.net/adonegan/zsnovq5L/28/)

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<!--Temperature Block-->
<div style="width: 600px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: black;">
  <div id="containerinternalTemp" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
  <div id="containerexternalTemp" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 $(function() {
   // Temperature Guage Options
   var temperatureGaugeOptions = {
     chart: {
       backgroundColor: null,
       type: 'solidgauge'
     },
     title: null,
     pane: {
       size: '90%',
       background: {
         backgroundColor: 'white',
         innerRadius: '93%',
         outerRadius: '102%',
         shape: 'arc'
       }
     },
     tooltip: {
       enabled: false
     },
     credits: {
       enabled: false
     },

     // the value axis
     yAxis: {
       stops: [
         [0, '#045ce2'],
         [0.1, '#045ce2'],
         [0.2, '#045ce2'],
         [0.25, '#045ce2'],
         [0.3, '#0489e2'],
         [0.4, '#0489e2'],
         [0.5, '#04cbe2'],
         [0.52, '#04cbe2'],
         [0.521, '#f9c527'],
         [0.6, '#f9a426'],
         [0.7, '#f98826'],
         [0.8, '#f95e26'],
         [0.9, '#f95e26']
       ],
       lineWidth: 0,
       minorTickInterval: 5,
       tickPixelInterval: 50,
       tickWidth: 1,
       labels: {
         style: {
           color: 'white'
         },
         enabled: true,
         distance: 12,
         useHTML: true
       }
     },
     plotOptions: {
       solidgauge: {
         innerRadius: '95%',
         dataLabels: {
           x: -20,
           y: 35,
           borderWidth: 0,
           useHTML: true
         }
       }
     }
   };

   // Internal Temperature
   $('#containerinternalTemp').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(temperatureGaugeOptions, {
     yAxis: {
       min: -15,
       max: 40,
     },
     pane: {
       startAngle: -180,
       endAngle: 0,
     },
     series: [{
       name: 'inTemp',
       data: [13],
       dataLabels: {
         style: {
           color: 'orange',
         },
         format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;">{y}&deg;C</span><br/>' + '<span style="font-size:10px;color:white">Internal</span></div>'
       }
     }]
   }));

   // External Temperature
   $('#containerexternalTemp').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(temperatureGaugeOptions, {
     yAxis: {
       min: -15,
       max: 40,
     },
     pane: {
       startAngle: 180,
       endAngle: 0
     },
     series: [{
       name: 'exTemp',
       data: [5],
       dataLabels: {
         style: {
           color: 'orange',
         },
         format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;">{y}&deg;C</span><br/>' + '<span style="font-size:10px;color:white">External</span></div>'
       }
     }]
   }));
 });
```

I have tried various settings and the closest results I can achieve is below using the reversed:true option and having the start angle lower than the end angle, the only problem being that the plot line is drawn from a start point of 40. I require it to start from -15 and draw up to 5.

[image]
[Js Fiddle for second result](http://jsfiddle.net/adonegan/bnL5osh2/7/)

Javascript - The only change is the reversed: true added on the yAxis and the start and end angle for the pane.

```
// External Temperature
   $('#containerexternalTemp').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(temperatureGaugeOptions, {
     yAxis: {
       min: -15,
       max: 40,
       reversed: true
     },
     pane: {
       startAngle: 0,
       endAngle: 180
     },
     series: [{
       name: 'exTemp',
       data: [5],
       dataLabels: {
         style: {
           color: 'orange',
         },
         format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;">{y}&deg;C</span><br/>' + '<span style="font-size:10px;color:white">External</span></div>'
       }
     }]
   }));
```

I have searched and found an issue from 2015 with Solid Gauge charts [HERE](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4434) and trying to do what I have done. This issue looks to have been fixed and I can not find anything else to show this being an outstanding problem with Highcharts platform.

Many thanks in advance from anyone who takes the time to read and review this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is a problem with automating calculation of the tick positions when endAngle is greater than startAngle. You can force the tick positions by setting axis [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions) or [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner). In your case, you can grab the tick positions from the first gauge chart in the tick positioner callback.

```
 yAxis: {
   min: -15,
   max: 40,
   //  reversed: true
   tickPositioner: function() {
     var tickPositions = $('#containerinternalTemp').highcharts().yAxis[0].tickPositions
     return tickPositions;
   }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/egr0ge11/

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time much appreciated and it provides exactly what we are hoping for.